# Not sure about input impedance of this PNP transistor circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, pnp, input-impedance

I have to find the input impedance *Zi* of the following circuit:

[image]

Using the small signal equivalent for the transistor, I get the following schematic:

[image]

It is easy to see, that we need to write the nodes B and C, whose equations are:

*Node B: VB/hie + VB/RB - VC/RB = IB*

*Node C: IC/VT*VB + VC*hoe = IC*

After, I want to find the impedance as *Zi = VB/IB*, but I can't get to that, as I always end up stuck with VB in the middle the IB equation or vice versa. Up to this point, I doubt if I am approaching this problem propperly (I am quite rusty with this kind of circuits). Any idea is welcome!

Comment: It looks like you have two equations in two unknowns, and you can choose what to solve for.  So -- solve for \$i_b\$ and \$v_c\$ as a function of \$v_b\$, with plain old algebra.  That should give you both the gain and the input impedance.

Comment: You may want to check the course material: at least, when I was learning this stuff 40 years ago, when you get to this sort of problem you're expected to use feedback theory to make the job easier.  In that context, turning in homework solving it using nodal analysis directly would be in error.  So you'd be identifying the kind of circuit it is (voltage amplifier, current amplifier, transimpedance amplifier or transconductance amplifier), then you'd find the gain and input impedance without feedback, then you'd apply feedback to find the gain and input impedance _with_ feedback.

Comment: Miqueas, The input impedance will be almost entirely determined by the DC quiescent operating point of the BJT -- namely, \$r_\pi\$. The value of \$R_b\$ is negligible and so is the Early Effect. They just don't matter here. So \$h_\text{ie}\$ is the input impedance as seen by the source. Full stop. The output impedance as seen by the load is similarly simple. The Early Effect can be ignored and \$R_b\$ is too large to matter, as well. It's almost entirely determined by \$R_c\$.

Comment: Hi guys! Thank you for your answer. As Tim said first, it was old plain algebra. The impedance is something like 2.5kOhm.